# Python Using Dijkstra’s Algorithm To Find Possible Paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have some X and Y points that are output by another program and I am wondering if there is a way to use Dijkstra's algorithm to plan the most probable path for connecting all of the points?

**For Example**

```
                           ----4------5
                           |
8------7-----6----[0]------1-------2-----3
       |
    9---
```

The `[0]` in the example will be the starting point and the numbers will be the points from the imported file. Let's say those points are..

```
point    X    Y
  1      2    0
  2      4    0
  3      6    0
  0      0    0
  4      2.5  2.5
  5      4.5  2.5
  6      -2   0
  7      -4   0
  8      -6   0
  9      -4.5 -2.5
```

After those points are sent into the Dijkstra's algorithm I would like the output path to be something like...

```
output= {
            '0': ['1', '6'],
            '1': ['2', '4'],
            '2': ['3'],
            '4': ['5'],
            '6': ['7'],
            '7': ['8','9']
            }
```

If you noticed the point `0` might not be at the very beginning of the data but could be somewhere in the middle. Also, the output includes all of the points, none of them are left out.

The code that I have kinda working seems to leave points out when the numbers get big, which is why I would like to use Dijkstra's instead. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Some what working code**

```
import math, collections
data = {0.0: [0.0, 0.0], 1.0: [1.0, 0.0], 2.0: [2.0, 0.0], 3.0: [3.0, 0.0], 4.0: [1.5, 0.5], 5.0: [2.5, 0.5], 6.0: [-1.0, 0.0], 7.0: [-2.0, 0.0], 8.0: [-3.0, 0.0], 9.0: [-2.5, -0.5]}
def group(d, start, seen = []):
   x, y = d[start]
   r = [a for a, [j, k] in d.items() if a != start and a not in seen and math.hypot(abs(x-j), abs(y-k)) <= 1]
   if not r:
     return {}
   result = {start:r}
   for i in r:
     result.update(group(d, i, seen+[start, *r]))
   return result

result = group(data, 0)
```

I found an example of Dijkstra's algorithm [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)

**Dijkstra's Algorithm**

```
import sys

class Graph():

    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.V = vertices
        self.graph = [[0 for column in range(vertices)]
                      for row in range(vertices)]

    def printSolution(self, dist):
        print("Vertex tDistance from Source")
        for node in range(self.V):
            print(node, "t", dist[node])

    # A utility function to find the vertex with
    # minimum distance value, from the set of vertices
    # not yet included in shortest path tree
    def minDistance(self, dist, sptSet):

        # Initilaize minimum distance for next node
        min = sys.maxsize

        # Search not nearest vertex not in the
        # shortest path tree
        for v in range(self.V):
            if dist[v] < min and sptSet[v] == False:
                min = dist[v]
                min_index = v

        return min_index

    # Funtion that implements Dijkstra's single source
    # shortest path algorithm for a graph represented
    # using adjacency matrix representation
    def dijkstra(self, src):

        dist = [sys.maxsize] * self.V
        dist[src] = 0
        sptSet = [False] * self.V

        for cout in range(self.V):

            # Pick the minimum distance vertex from
            # the set of vertices not yet processed.
            # u is always equal to src in first iteration
            u = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet)

            # Put the minimum distance vertex in the
            # shotest path tree
            sptSet[u] = True

            # Update dist value of the adjacent vertices
            # of the picked vertex only if the current
            # distance is greater than new distance and
            # the vertex in not in the shotest path tree
            for v in range(self.V):
                if self.graph[u][v] > 0 and sptSet[v] == False and \
                dist[v] > dist[u] + self.graph[u][v]:
                        dist[v] = dist[u] + self.graph[u][v]

        self.printSolution(dist)

# Driver program
g = Graph(9)
g.graph = [[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
           [4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0],
           [0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
           [0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6],
           [8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7],
           [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0]
          ];

g.dijkstra(0);
# This code is contributed by Divyanshu Mehta
```

Comment: I would recommend using `networkx` for graphs. [These](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.2/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html) are the algorithms for shortest paths implemented there.

Comment: What you want is called [Euclidean minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree)

Comment: @juvian thank you for your response, I will start looking into the minimum spanning tree

Comment: [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/) is a how to build minimum spanning tree based on manhattan distance if you prefer that.